# Rails Reporting Wrong Environment in Multi-stage Setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, passenger

Using capistrano 2.12.0, capistrano-ext 1.2.1, Rails 3.2.7 and Phusion Passenger 3.0.15.

For no logical reason, my 'playground' server has started reporting that it's actually running in development mode.

I've reinstalled things, restarted apache etc but am still stuck.

Don't really want to hardcode as I've got a production environment to think about.

In my apache conf. I've set

```
RailsEnv playground
```

There's a [gist of my deploy.rb file here](https://gist.github.com/3314266)

Capistrano is sending to the correct location etc. so I think it's rails or passenger rather than cap.

What else can I do to get this going properly??

---- EDIT ----

I've just tested with Unicorn and it's also reporting that it's running in development mode.

Starting unicorn with the following:

```
 unicorn -E playground -l 8000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much experimentation, I found the root cause to be a line in one of my models:

```
 - if Rails.env = 'development'
```

Obviously, this should have been a '==' not a single one.

Comment: Wow, this was driving me crazy.  I had the same issue.  Thanks.

Comment: You'll only do that once :)

Comment: For anyone else stumbling upon this: It's probably better to call `Rails.env.development?` :)